# Find $n(R\cap Q)$ if $R=\{(x,y)$:$x^2$+$3y^2$=$28,x$,$y\in\mathbb{Z}\}$ and $Q$=$\{(x,y)$:$x$>$y,x$,$y\in\mathbb{Z}\}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, diophantine-equations, relations

> Th relations $R=\{(x,y):x^2+3y^2=28,x,y\in\mathbb{Z}\}$ and $Q=\{(x,y):x>y,x,y\in\mathbb{Z}\}$, then the number of elements in $R\cap Q$ is ?

how do I find the integer solutions of the equation $x^2+3y^2=28$ ?

**Note**: If it was a first order Diophantine equation I know how to solve, but what is the easiest way to solve second order Diophantine equations of such types ?

Comment: I suppose this is easier to solve, since squares are constrained (in the reals) to be $\ge 0$

Comment: Assume $x,y\ge 0$, and then generate the full set of solutions accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As $x^2+3y^2=28$ you can easily see that $x^2=28-3y^2\le28$, so $|x|\le \sqrt{28}=2\sqrt{7}$. Similarly you can get the estimate for $y$. Then you just have to enumerate all the possibilities.

Comment: You are going backwards with $|x|\le 2\sqrt 7$. From $x^2\le 28$ we get immediately that $x\le 5$.

Comment: thanx. but is it easy to solve the equation $x^2+3y^2=28$ for integer solutions, i mean is there any formal ways to solve without finding the limits as we have it for first order Diophantine equations ?

Comment: @ss1729 You might want to know about **Pell's equation**. That kind of equations looks like yours, while containing infinitely many solutions.